# Troubles with Dovecot 2.3.3 - mkdir permission denied due to +w perm: /var, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)

Tags: linux, mail-server, dovecot

I have installed postfix mail server on ubuntu 20.04 server and I am getting the following errors on dovecot when I run command:

```
sudo journalctl -eu dovecot
```

> Jan 30 13:44:54 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: lmtp(298030): Connect from local
> Jan 30 13:44:54 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: lmtp(info)<298030>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=075>
> Jan 30 13:44:54 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: lmtp(info)<298030>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=075>
> Jan 30 13:44:54 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: lmtp(info)<298030>: Error: lmtp-server: conn unix:pid=298029,uid=116 [2]: rcpt info@wokforge.com: Mailbox INBOX: Failed to autocreate mailbox: Internal error occ>
> Jan 30 13:44:54 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: lmtp(info)<298030>: msgid=20220128054541.9AE1FC0EA1@mail.wokforge.com: save failed to open mailbox INBOX: Mailbox INBOX: Failed to autocreate mailbox: Internal>
> Jan 30 13:44:54 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: lmtp(298030): Disconnect from local: Client has quit the connection (state=READY)
> Jan 30 13:45:19 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap-login: Login: user=, method=PLAIN, rip=197.156.190.166, lip=10.0.0.165, mpid=298034, TLS, session=<Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: Mailbox Drafts: Failed to autocreate mailbox: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2022-01-30 13:45:21]
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: Mailbox Junk: Failed to autocreate mailbox: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2022-01-30 13:45:21]
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: Mailbox Trash: Failed to autocreate mailbox: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2022-01-30 13:45:21]
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: Mailbox INBOX: Failed to autocreate mailbox: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information. [2022-01-30 13:45:21]
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)
> Jan 30 13:45:21 mail.wokforge.com dovecot[297622]: imap(info)<298034><Q+P04MzWOlrFnL6m>: Error: mkdir(/home/info/Maildir) failed: Permission denied (euid=1002(info) egid=1002(info) missing +w perm: /home, dir owned by 0:0 mode=0755)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory `/home/info/` seems not existing. Try create dir with `sudo mkdir -p /home/info/Maildir` and change ownerchip `sudo chown -R info:info /home/info`

Comment: Hello. Thanks David. You saved my day. I can now receive mails on my mail server but however I am unable to send them. All mails i sent, bounce back. I  ran the following command to check error logs on post fix:  sudo tail -f -n 50 /var/log/syslog | grep postfix

Comment: Here are the results: Feb  1 13:43:28 mail postfix/smtp[320519]: DE6EEC0E91: to=<tchesoen@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c01::1b]:25, delay=2.3, delays=0.25/0/1.7/0.36, dsn=5.7.26, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c01::1b] said: 550-5.7.26 Unauthenticated email from wokforge.com is not accepted due to 550-5.7.26 domain's DMARC policy.

Comment: You have a SPF entry for wokforge.com enabled, but you allow only your v4 IP-Address, not your IPv6. You have to add ip6:xxxx:xxxx:... to your SPF :)